# After using Jquery to refresh DIV, CSS not working on Div

Tags: php, jquery, html, scroll, refresh

I have a div that is being refreshed after a user click on a link.

Here's my CSS for that Div:

```
#groups_wrapper {
height: 150px;
width: 250px;
overflow: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Here's my Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- AJAX CALL FOR MY GROUPS -->
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.delete_group').live('click', function(e){
 $('#groups_wrapper').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' #groups_wrapper', function() { 
  $(".item_control_box").hide();
  jQuery('.each_item_container').hover(function() {
   jQuery(this).find('.item_control_box').show()
   }, function() {
   jQuery(this).find('.item_control_box').hide();
  });
 }); 
 e.preventDefault(); 
}); 
});
</script>
```

Here my html:

```
<a href='delete.php?id=x' class='delete_group'>Delete Group</a>
```

The issue I'm running into is that when the user clicks on the Link to delete a group, the div refreshed but is unable to scroll up and down on the particular div,  I have my CSS set to

```
 overflow: auto;
 overflow-x:hidden;
```

Any ideas why this would be breaking?

Comment: Your HTML is missing in the question?

Comment: Yeah, can't figure out how to add the html..

Comment: where are you putting your css. and please include ur html.

Comment: @DobotJr You have to indent the HTML likeusual code samples with four spaces. You can paste it and someoneelse can edit it, if you are unable to indent it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the line:

```
overflow: auto;
```

To:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Comment: Tried, didn't work. I don't thins its an issue with the CSS because when I refresh the page it works.  The issue is when the div is being refreshed with jquery. It's like I need to also reload the CSS after the div is refreshed..idk.